# Issues linking C files in XCode

Tags: c, xcode

I will start by mentioning that my experience with compiling C code is limited, and it is possible that what I am trying to do is not even possible. However, I have had success doing similar to use Objective-C code with a bridging file, and was hoping the same would apply when using plain C files.

I am attempting to use the source files from the [dfu-programmer project](https://github.com/dfu-programmer/dfu-programmer/) to build a simple GUI version.

Note: I did first successfully compile the source from terminal by following the instructions and using the makefile, but have not had success doing so in XCode.

I first wanted to try building the program as-is as a console application through XCode, and no matter what I try I continue getting the same results. Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Created a new console application in XCode
2. Added all the .c and .h files to the project
3. Added "/usr/local/include/**" to the Header, Framework, and Library search paths. This is where my libusb.h and usb.h live.
4. Build

My build always fails with the same linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_debug", referenced from:
  _stm32_read_flash in stm32.o
  _print_progress in stm32.o
  _stm32_write_flash in stm32.o
  _parse_arguments in arguments.o
  _assign_global_options in arguments.o
  _print_args in arguments.o
  _atmel_read_flash in atmel.o
  ...
 (maybe you meant: _dfu_debug)
  "_usb_claim_interface", referenced from:
  _dfu_device_init in dfu.o
```

And so on...

From what I can tell, all the undefined symbols it's looking for are from libusb.h. It appears like it finds this okay to compile the .h and .c files, but then fails when it tries to link the .o files afterwards.

I'm hoping that I'm just missing something in my XCode settings to make this work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you add the library to the linking stage?

Comment: Check your linking against the necessary library and including the header files which needed. If you use Makefile you can include header file dir in compilation as -I<include>

Comment: I had not linked the libraries in the "Link Binary with Libraries" section of the Build Phases, because I didn't know how to link them if they didn't show up in the list (they were in the hidden /usr/... directories). After googling and finding the Shift-Cmd-G shortcut I was able to type the locations directly. I believe it worked, because now I'm down to only one set of errors remaining, which I think is being caused by each C file having its own definition of a DEBUG(...) macro, which XCode warns as "DEBUG macro redefined" each time. Guess XCode doesn't like this? I'll have to rename them.